# css drop down menu can hover on text only

Tags: css, text, drop-down-menu, hover

When using my css dropdown menu only the text of the dropdown is active which makes it more difficult to select rather than the area which would be easier (especially with mobile devices).

CSS is:

```
#topMenu ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 20px 17px 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
#topMenu ul li {
  font: bold 12px sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#666;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: #EEE;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
#topMenu ul li:hover {
  background: #EEE;
  color: #000;
}
#topMenu ul li ul {
z-index: 5000;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
#topMenu ul li ul li { 
  background: #EEE; 
  display: block; 
  color: #000;
  border:solid 1px #999999;
}
#topMenu ul li ul li:hover { background: #EEE; }
#topMenu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;

  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Code may be a bit cumbersome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you put your html code too?

Comment: @Romain that's the tricky bit you have to figure out that for yourself :) joking aside. Here OP use this website http://jsfiddle.net to display your code in the future

Comment: @htmltroll It's better for legacy if its posted on here first.

Comment: @Xareyo you are right, but overwhelming people with this amount of code isn't good, better would be in my opinion to straight go for the fiddle and leave snippets of css and html explain the problem you are having

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:block;` to your anchor tag CSS to make it fill the `li`.

CSS:

```
#topMenu ul li ul a {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="topMenu">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link Text</a>
      </li>
      <!-- more submenu items -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- more topMenu items -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this <---> instead of use `padding:10px 40px` to determine the height use this:

```
line-height:30px <---- it replaces the padding top and bottom (20px) and add 10px of the font.
```

Then your CSS could be:

```
#topMenu ul li {
 font: bold 12px sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#666;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -4px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px 40px;
 line-height:30px;
 background: #EEE;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

If you have `a` tags inside the `li` then make it block and the same line-height:

```
#topmenu ul li a {
  display:block;
  line-height:30px;
  height:30px;
}
```